# Magento 2: how to set Can Show Price Attribute - $product->getCanShowPrice()?

Tags: magento2, price

**How to set Can Show Price Attribute** - `$product->getCanShowPrice()`? There is a config for product or admin?

Comment: Have you looked at what this function does internally? I believe it does some sort of computation to know whether or not a price can be shown.

Comment: @JulienLachal Is there a config for product or admin?

Answer (score 3):

```
$product->setCanShowPrice(true|false);
```

Comment: There is a config or product attribute?